# C# Drag&Drop, hard time selecting draggable panel because of content

Tags: c#, layout, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a (rather small) Panel full of labels and a few other controls. 
I've made this panel draggable, but because of the size and content there are only a few "holes" which actually activate the drag&drop (e.g. corners).

Is there a way to display all the labels on "the background" of the panel so that I can click anywhere on the Panel to trigger the dragevent?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[i think this link might help you...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773860/net-usercontrol-drag-drop-child-controls)
you would want to allow the children to drag and drop the parent control instead of moving your controls to the background of the panel

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch Yugz!

Comment: You can possible automate it by subscribing to [ControlAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded.aspx) event (and ControlRemoved) and subsribing on all child events required for drag-n-drop. Then you can forward them to the parent control (with EventArg substitution), so when you touch a Label, your Panel feels "touched". =D